# Can we configure both set and list types for different multimaps in hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I am using a multimap as a set in hazelcast but there is a requirement for the use of multimap  both as a list and a set(two different multimaps with the same client).Changing hazelcast.xml I can either have a SET type multimap or a LIST type multimap.Is there a way to have both types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely possible. Include this in your hazelcast.xml

```
<multimap name="set*">
    <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
</multimap>

<multimap name="list*">
    <value-collection-type>LIST</value-collection-type>
</multimap>
```

All multimaps with a name starting with a prefix "set-" with use a set to store elements and multimaps starting with a prefix "list" will use a list.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer.But is there any way to assign the type of map through client code in clientconfig?

Comment: I don't think so. Type of maps is determined by server config.